# Odoo report error (translate_doc....)

Tags: report, odoo

I've modified a report in Odoo and am trying to display some data when I print an invoice. Currently I am having a problem with a field which I've created myself. I'm trying to call the field as below:

```
<span t-field="company.payment_methods"/>
```

however when I try and print the report I get the error message:

QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'" while evaluating
"translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'account.report_invoice_document')"

Any help getting around this error? If I take out that field then I don't get the same error and it just prints normally

Thanks

Comment: Since you are in the invoice object you cant call payment methods like that. You can, either make a function or put that field in invoice model.

Comment: There must be a way to call fields from other objects?

Comment: Yes, you can use functions to get that object and return the field